# Proof of Fejer's lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis, fejer-kernel

How does ont prove Fejer's lemma:

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$, then
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f(t) g(nt) \, dt = \hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0).$

Comment: Approximate f i the $L^1$ by polynomials

Comment: I think that the following path could bring you to a proof. Fix an arbitrary trigonometric polynomial $f$ and an arbitrary characteristic function $g$ of an interval $(a,b)$. Prove the conclusion using brute force in this case. Then by the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem (or something like that), extend the result for an arbitrary characteristic function $g$ of a Borel-measurable set. Then, by linearity and bounded convergence, extend the result for an arbitrary $g\in L^\infty$ function. Finally, by the density of trigonometric polynomials in $L^1$, extend the result to get the conclusion

Answer (score 1):

Show that it's enough to prove it assuming $f$ is a trigonomtric polynomial. Figure out the Fourier coefficients of $g(nt)$ in terms of $\hat g(k)$.

Comment: C.Ullrich  I have seen that continuous functions on thr circle can be uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials. So I assume it is enough to show it for $f$ trigonometric. Also,  $\hat{g}(nt)=\hat{g} (t/n)$ if t|n and 0 otherwise. Now im stuck

Comment: @Bach That's not a valid counterexample to the correct statement of what's needed here. **If $f$ has period $2\pi$** then in fact $\int_0^{2\pi}f(2x)\sin(7x)\,dx=0$. Your example does not contradict this because there is no $2\pi$ function $f$ with $f(2x)=2x$ for all $x\in]0.2\pi]$.

Comment: (where of course "$2\pi$ function" was supposed to be "$2\pi$-periodic function"...)

Comment: (key to proof: $\sin(7(x+\pi))=-\sin(7x)$.)

Comment: Its obvious there is no such $f$. We would have $f(2\pi)=2\pi$ and $f(0)=0$, hence $f$ is not $2\pi$-[eriodic.

Comment: Doesn't the above construction work, you ask. **What** "construction"? You haven't said what function $f$ you have in mind!

Comment: @Bach I didn't see that you'd left two comments, sorry. The function you define above does not satisfy $f(2x)=2x$ for every $x\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Bach Why do I say$f(2\pi)=2\pi$? Come on now! We're assuming that $f(2x)=2x$ for $x\in[0.2\pi]$. Let $x=\pi$.

Comment: @Bach Re "I define the values of f on [0,2π], then we can extend f to be periodic on R. Like a sawtooth wave. So what do you want to say? ": I want to say what I've said: Doing this cannot give you a $2\pi$-periodic $f$ with $f(2x)=2x$ on $[0,2\pi]$.